# Strange deadlock PostgreSQL deadlock issue with SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transactions, deadlock

I am building a locking system based on PostgreSQL, I have two methods, `acquire` and `release`.

For `acquire`, it works like this

```
BEGIN
while True:
    SELECT id FROM my_locks WHERE locked = false AND id = '<NAME>' FOR UPDATE
    if no rows return:
        continue
    UPDATE my_locks SET locked = true WHERE id = '<NAME>'
    COMMIT
    break
```

And for `release`

```
BEGIN
UPDATE my_locks SET locked = false WHERE id = '<NAME>'
COMMIT
```

This looks pretty straightforward, but it doesn't work. The strange part of it is, I thought

```
SELECT id FROM my_locks WHERE locked = false AND id = '<NAME>' FOR UPDATE
```

should only acquire the lock on target row only if the target row's `locked` is `false`. But in reality, it's not like that. Somehow, even no `locked = false` row exists, it acquire lock anyway. As a result, I have a deadlock issue. It looks like this

[image: Select for update dead lock issue]

Release is waiting for `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, and `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is doing infinite loop while it's holding a lock for no reason.

To reproduce the issue, I wrote a simple test here

https://gist.github.com/victorlin/d9119dd9dfdd5ac3836b

You can run it with `psycopg2` and `pytest`, remember to change the database setting, and run

```
pip install pytest psycopg2
py.test -sv test_lock.py
```

Comment: What is your isolation level?  In particular, are you using `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE`?

Comment: @Kevin I didn't change the isolation config, so I think that's the default value, I think that should be `REPEATABLE READ`, will check it later

Comment: The default value is `READ COMMITTED`.

Comment: @Kevin yes, it is `READ COMMITTED`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The test case plays out like this:

- Thread-1 runs the `SELECT` and acquires the record lock.
- Thread-2 runs the `SELECT` and enters the lock's wait queue.
- Thread-1 runs the `UPDATE` / `COMMIT` and releases the lock.
- Thread-2 acquires the lock. Detecting that the record has changed since its `SELECT`, it rechecks the data against its `WHERE` condition. The check fails, and the row is filtered out of the result set, but the lock is still held.

This behaviour is mentioned in the [`FOR UPDATE` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE):

> ...rows that satisfied the query conditions as of the query snapshot will be locked, although they will not be returned if they were updated after the snapshot and no longer satisfy the query conditions.

This can have some [unpleasant consequences](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/002501ccfa9a$f923ead0$eb6bc070$@hellosam.net), so a superfluous lock isn't *that* bad, all things considered.

Probably the simplest workaround is to limit the lock duration by committing after every iteration of `acquire`. There are various other ways to prevent it from holding this lock (e.g. `SELECT ... NOWAIT`, running in a `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, [`SELECT ... SKIP LOCKED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) in Postgres 9.5).

I think the cleanest implementation using this retry-loop approach would be to skip the `SELECT` altogether, and just run an `UPDATE ... WHERE locked = false`, committing each time. You can tell if you acquired the lock by checking `cur.rowcount` after calling `cur.execute()`. If there is additional information you need to pull from the lock record, you can use an `UPDATE ... RETURNING` statement.

But I would have to agree with [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31929467/1104979), and say that you'd probably be better off leveraging Postgres' built-in locking support than trying to reinvent it. It would solve a lot of problems for you, e.g.:

- Deadlocks are automatically detected
- Waiting processes are put to sleep, rather than having to poll the server
- Lock requests are queued, preventing starvation
- Locks would (generally) not outlive a failed process

The easiest way might be to implement `acquire` as `SELECT FROM my_locks FOR UPDATE`, `release` simply as `COMMIT`, and let the processes contend for the row lock. If you need more flexibility (e.g. blocking/non-blocking calls, transaction/session/custom scope), [advisory locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) should prove useful.

Comment: There really is no need to busy wait given that Postgres can simply make a thread wait. `locked` is unnecessary, we can just use the UPDATE lock associated with an id's row. This leads directly to your last paragraph `acquire`/`release`.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL [normally](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-DEADLOCKS) aborts transactions which deadlock:

> The use of explicit locking can increase the likelihood of deadlocks, wherein two (or more) transactions each hold locks that the other wants. For example, if transaction 1 acquires an exclusive lock on table A and then tries to acquire an exclusive lock on table B, while transaction 2 has already exclusive-locked table B and now wants an exclusive lock on table A, then neither one can proceed. **PostgreSQL automatically detects deadlock situations and resolves them by aborting one of the transactions involved**, allowing the other(s) to complete. (Exactly which transaction will be aborted is difficult to predict and should not be relied upon.)

Looking at your Python code, and at the screenshot you showed, it appears to me that:

- Thread 3 is holding the `locked=true` lock, and is [waiting to acquire a row lock](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS).
- Thread 1 is also waiting for a row lock, and also the `locked=true` lock.
- The only logical conclusion is that Thread 2 is somehow holding the row lock, and waiting for the `locked=true` lock (note the short time on that query; it is looping, not blocking).

Since Postgres is not aware of the `locked=true` lock, it is unable to abort transactions to prevent deadlock in this case.

It's not immediately clear to me how T2 acquired the row lock, since all the information I've looked at says [it can't do that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS):

> FOR UPDATE causes **the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement** to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being locked, modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That is, other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT FOR UPDATE, SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE, SELECT FOR SHARE or SELECT FOR KEY SHARE of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends; conversely, SELECT FOR UPDATE will wait for a concurrent transaction that has run any of those commands on the same row, and will then **lock and return the updated row (or no row, if the row was deleted)**. Within a REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE transaction, however, an error will be thrown if a row to be locked has changed since the transaction started. For further discussion see Section 13.4.

I was not able to find any evidence of PostgreSQL "magically" upgrading row locks to table locks or anything similar.

But what you're doing is not obviously safe, either.  You're acquiring lock A (the row lock), then acquiring lock B (the explicit `locked=true` lock), then releasing and re-acquiring A, before finally releasing B and A in that order.  This does not properly observe a lock hierarchy since we try both to acquire A while holding B and *vice-versa*.  But OTOH, acquiring B while holding A should not fail (I think), so I'm still not sure this is outright wrong.

---

Quite frankly, it's my opinion that you'd be better off just using the [`LOCK TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-lock.html) statement on an empty table.  Postgres is aware of these locks and will detect deadlocks for you.  It also saves you the trouble of the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` finagling.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you should add `locked = true` in the release code:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE my_locks SET locked = false WHERE id = '<NAME>' AND locked = true
COMMIT
```

If not, you are updating the record whatever locked state it is (in your case, even when locked = false), and adding the odds of causing a deadlock.